# Where to place custom assets?

Tags: java, libgdx, assets

I have several custom assets like `csv` files. Where should i put these to make sure they will be found for each build/project (`Desktop`/`IOS`/`Android`)? I already tried the `android/assets` folder but the file is not found by the `BufferedReader`. Should i just keep my csv files there and navigate to that folder with the `BufferedReader` or is this incompatible between the different projects? Bonus points for including a proper way to navigate to correct map, i can look this up but worry about compatibility between projects.

I tried giving a LibGDX FileHandle as a paremeter to the BufferedReader without results. It just does not accept a LibGDX filehandle.

```
FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("roomsets.csv");

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(handle)); //The constructor FileReader(FileHandle) is undefined

br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(handle).read()); //error: The constructor BufferedReader(int) is undefined

br = new BufferedReader(handle); //The constructor BufferedReader(FileHandle) is undefined
```

I fixed it with this:

```
br = new BufferedReader(handle.reader());
```

Just curious now if this should would bring up issues on IOS and Android?

Comment: if you're not already, make sure you're using libgdx's [file system](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) to get handles to your files, rather than creating handles to them yourself. As in, don't do new File("your_path.csv"), instead do something like Gdx.files.internal("your_path.csv") and then get the file that way

Comment: @clearlyspam23 I tried that actually, but i cannot get the BufferedReader or FileReader to work with libgdx FileHandles.

Comment: what is the error message you're getting? can you maybe post it on the question?

Comment: @clearlyspam23 It just does not except LibGdx FileHandles as a parameter.

Comment: I think i figured it out. (br = new BufferedReader(handle.reader());) seems to read it properly.

Comment: Actually handle.reader(); returns in its own a reader so you could do br = handle.reader(buffersize);

Comment: Yeah, i have seen that but it does not have all the functionality the BufferReader has. Like readline, but then again i could just put the whole file in a string and go from there.